# Multiple XHR requests from React Component

Tags: reactjs

Given the following React app, it will make two requests to the jsonplaceholder API, why does this happen and can it be prevented so it only performs one?

```
import { useMemo } from "react";

class Client {
  constructor() {
    this.setup()
  }
  setup = async() => {
    console.log("setup")
    await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
  }
}

export default function App() {
  useMemo(() => { return new Client() }, [])
  return null
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-water-91t3in?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when using strict mode as react invokes certain functions twice . It also patches `console.log` on the second run which makes debugging hard. More information here: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html